# I clicked some stupid "feature" in Eclipse and now my enviroment is screwed up

Tags: eclipse

This is what it looks like:

[image]

And when I double click on one of the files in the coding tab (which you would think would fullscreen the coding window), it turns into this:

[image]

What the hell "feature" did I accidentally enable and how do I disable this?

I will also add that when I close and reopen eclipse it is still glitched out.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

*edit:*

Let me add that it looks like this:

[image]

when I first load up elclipse now, but then when I full screen a coding tab and then unfullscreen it it comes back all glitched out like in that first image.

Anybody? How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same thing a few times when I was first learning Eclipse, there are a lot of items on the workbench.  I have no idea what I clicked to mess it up.

I found that: Window Menu -> Reset Perspective .. fixed it however.

Comment: I did that and it mostly fixed it but then there was still this gray square blocking out the screen, so my eclipse was definitely glitched in a very weird way. Once I restarted eclipse though it was back to normal.